# Is there an auto trigger of SYNC request with some frequency?

Tags: google-smart-home

It seems that there are the following options to trigger SYNC request:

- account linking
- manual call by user via sync device phrase
- via requestSync

Is there an auto trigger of SYNC request with some frequency?

Answer (score 0):

No, SYNC intents will not be periodically sent to your service without some sort of prompt such as the three you mention: linking an account, the command "sync my devices", or sending requestSync from your service.